# Add Spaces or Line Breaks to Facebook Page Posts via Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I am posting to a facebook profile page as the page using curl and Graph API. I need to add some simple line breaks or just some spaces in order to format the post text. Is there any way to do this as I have tried many things but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook->api("me/feed","POST",array("message" => "Hey"."
    "." world"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using a normal `\n` line feed inside of your `message` content should work perfectly fine in posts made via the API from PHP.

Comment: Can you please give an example ? I am unable to understand it !

Comment: @SKG what is there to understand …?

Comment: Actually, I have tried \n in the message to insert new line in my fb status update using graph api, but It's not working I have also tried, <center></center>, '\n\r', '%0D%0A' but nothing seems to work !!